# Stop Notification sound when Notification clicked android

Tags: java, android

I am building an android application which show notification with custom sound, when user click this notification I start an activity.
all of that working well for me but when user clicked notification sound still playing I want to stop the sound when user clicked on notification How can I do that.
this is my code

```
public void ShowNotification(String title,String message) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("com.mkandeel.test","Notification",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            NotificationManager manager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,"com.mkandeel.test");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notif)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity2.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,99,
                intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(pi);

        NotificationManagerCompat mcompact = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

        Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sound);

        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, sound);
        mp.start();

        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        
        mcompact.notify(99,builder.build());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found solution to create MediaPlayer object global variable and send boolean extra in intent as true
and in MainActivity2 I got this boolean variable and if it is true I accessed MediaPlayer object and stop it and this is modified code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public MediaPlayer mp;
    private Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        btn = findViewById(R.id.button);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ShowNotification("Test notification","Hello World!");
            }
        });

    }

public void ShowNotification(String title,String message) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("com.mkandeel.test","Notification",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            NotificationManager manager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,"com.mkandeel.test");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notif)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity2.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
        intent.putExtra("clicked",true);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,99,
                intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(pi);

        NotificationManagerCompat mcompact = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

        Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sound);

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, sound);
        mp.start();

        builder.setAutoCancel(true);

        mcompact.notify(99,builder.build());
    }
}
```

and in ***MainActivity2.java***

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        MainActivity activity = new MainActivity();

        boolean clicked = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("clicked",false);
        if (clicked) {
            activity.mp.stop();
            activity.mp.release();
        }
    }
}
```